# Find the leading behavior as $x \to 0+$ of $\int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t^2} dt$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm having trouble starting with this problem. I was thinking of using the Laplace method, but that requires $x \to \infty$. Is there another method that works for $x \to 0$?

Comment: What is the issue in writing $e^{-xt}$ as its Maclaurin series, then performing termwise integration?

Comment: I attempted that but the result I got didn’t seem to make much sense (I couldn’t find a pattern)

Comment: There is no pattern to find. Since $e^{-xt}=1-xt+O(x^2 t^2)$, the given integral behaves like $\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi x}{2}\log(2)+O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0^+$.